# Mouse Listener Issue

Tags: java, mouseevent

I'm currently building a bouncing ball application and have hit a bit of a snag. The idea is that the bouncing ball should be stationary until I have clicked with my mouse at which point I'd like to it to gain speed with each click. I can't seem to get the mouseClicked event to trigger though. Here is the code related to the Mouse Listener.

```
       public class MouseClick implements MouseListener {


       public void initialization(){

       addMouseListener(this);
       }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ballSpeedX +=1;
        ballSpeedY +=1;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

   }
```

Comment: Recommend posting an [mcve] to provide some context...for instance, when/where do you call `initialization`?

Comment: It makes no sense for your initialization() method to call `addMouseListener(this)` since MouseClick is not a JPanel.

Comment: Also, in mouseClicked you modify ballSpeed, but don't do anything that will cause any repaints of anything.